# Opacity on table-row in IE<9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, opacity, css-tables

I'm trying to set (and later change with javascript) the opacity.
But I can't make it work.
My HTML is:

```
<div class="table" >
  <div class="row" >
    <span>col1 test</span><span>col2</span><span>col3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row" >
    <span>col1</span><span>col2 test</span><span>col3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row" >
    <span>col1</span><span>col2</span><span>col3 test</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.table {display:table;}
.row {display:table-row;

      -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
        filter: alpha(opacity=20);
        -moz-opacity:0.2;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.2;
        opacity: 0.2;
}
.row span {display:table-cell;padding: 5px;}
```

OR [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buicu/rzHJQ/) AND [codepen](http://codepen.io/buicu/pen/aLvyf) (although they seem to crash in IE8 or IE7)

To test in IE8 & IE7, I'm changing the browser mode from IE9's dev tolls.
(if you are doing the same, make sure the browser mode & document mode are the same ).

Yes if I apply the opacity on the 'cell' it's working (but I need it on the row)

Does anyone has the some problem?

EDIT: this is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OCeTiKe/2/)

Any solutions?

Comment: Also, I just tested in Opera 12.16 and it also doesn't work

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't work below ie 9 - are you declaring a doctype in your document because old IE doesn't support those values unless a doctype is declared meaning display table-row

Comment: the jsfiddle embedded result page does work in old IE versions, just not the main fiddle UI, so create the fiddle in a newer browser, and then use the result URL to view it in IE8. But if you're still having trouble, http://jsbin.com/ is an alternative that works just fine in IE8.

Comment: @James Daly Yes I have one <!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: @Spudley Yes first I created the jsfiddle on Chrome29 and then copy paste the url in IE (IE9 works but on IE8 & IE7 it crashes, at least for me)

Comment: @silversky - in jsfiddle, click the share button, and see the "Share full screen result" URL. That URL should work in IE8.

Comment: off topic, but I see you're using `<div>` and `<span>` elements to create a table. Is this actually intended to be a table of data? I ask because it is valid to use the good old `<table>` / `<tr>` / `<td>` tags if they're being used for an actual table. It's not good to use them for building your page layout, but for something that is actually a table, please do use them.

Comment: a question: You say it works in cells but not in rows. What is the difference between setting it for each of the cells in the row, vs setting it on the row as a whole? Why is that not a viable solution for you?

Comment: @Spudley I also done it like you said http://jsfiddle.net/buicu/rzHJQ/ (which is the same like the link from the address bar). In IE8 is crashing. Can the problem be, because I'm changing the browser mode from IE9 dev tools?

Comment: @Spudley Actually I change it from a normal table/tr/td to a div/div/span just because I could change the opacity on the <tr> either

Comment: @Spudley regarding your Q, why I'm not using opacity on a cell is because later I changing the opacity with javascript (using a slider) and I have a loop for 'tr' and I don't want to make another loop for 'td' (it will slow down the code)

Comment: @Spudley Correction:  I missed that 'full screen'. The link is http://jsfiddle.net/buicu/rzHJQ/embedded/result/ Yes you are right  jsfiddle's website is working BUT the opacity is not working in IE 8&7